# error: not found: value sc

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and am trying to code read a file using the following code

```
scala> val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
scala> textFile.count()
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
error: not found: value sc
```

I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work. I am using Scala version 2.10.4 and Spark 1.1.0 (I have even tried Spark 1.2.0 but it doesn't work either). I have sbt installed and compiled yet not able to run `sbt/sbt assembly`. Is the error because of this?

Comment: is that all of it? It's pretty obvious this won't work, what is `sc`?

Comment: BTW, you should use Spark 1.4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run this code using `./spark-shell`. It's scala repl with provided sparkContext. You can find it in your apache spark distribution in folder `spark-1.4.1/bin`.

Comment: I used Spark-1.4.1 and ran the code per @ipoteka's advice. Works fine now