# Spark : Error Not found value SC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have just started with Spark. I have CDH5 Installed with Spark . However when I try to use sparkcontext it gives Error as below

```
<console>:17: error: not found: value sc
       val distdata = sc.parallelize(data)
```

I have researched about this and found [error: not found: value sc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625770/error-not-found-value-sc)

and tried to start spark context with ./spark-shell . It gives error `No such File or Directory`

Answer (score 5):

You can either start `spark-shell` starting with `./` if you're in its exact directory or `path/to/spark-shell` if you're elsewhere.

Also, if you're running a script with `spark-submit`, you need to initialize `sc` as `SparkContext` first:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have repeated all those Steps exactly . Still it gives same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're providing the right path to `spark-shell`? It's not in your system `/bin` by default, you have to execute it like `/path/to/spark-shell`

Comment: This is what I was doing . val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                                         val distData = sc.parallelize(data). Also How can I find path to spark shell ?

Comment: have you successfully started your `spark-shell` or did you just use your `scala` compiler?

Comment: `spark-shell` can be found in your spark directory at `bin/spark-shell`

Comment: Yes I have successfully started spark shell  by Issuing "spark-shell" as you suggested previously .

Comment: Do I have to do this groupId = org.apache.hadoop
artifactId = hadoop-client
version = <your-hdfs-version> as per SPARK DOC  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html ?

Comment: no these are irrelevant lines in terms of just running an application. did you try to initialize your own `SparkContext` as i suggested?

Comment: These 2 lines. val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf). Yes I did .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203815/spark-console12-error-not-found-value-sc  Here they say correct class path outside Repl ? I do not know if that is the Issues and how to correct class path outside Repl any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

There is another stackoverflow post that answers this question by getting sc(spark context) from spark session. I do it this way:

val **spark** = SparkSession.builder().appName("app_name").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val **sc** = **spark**.sparkContext

original answer here:
[Retrieve SparkContext from SparkSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659616/retrieve-sparkcontext-from-sparksession)

Answer (score 3):

Add spark directory to path then you may use spark-shell from anywhere.

Add `import org.apache.spark.SparkContext` if you are using it in a spark-submit job to create a spark context using:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

where conf is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new terminal fixes the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Hadoop daemons first (run this command "start-all.sh"). Then try

Answer (score 0):

you ca run this command   in spark(scala) prompt
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).