# Retrieve SparkContext from SparkSession

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running a spark batch job and uses `SparkSession` as I need a lot of spark-sql features to process in each of my components. 
The `SparkContext` is initialized in my parent component and been passed to the child components as `SparkSession`.

In one of my child components, I wanted to add two more configurations to my `SparkContext`. Hence, I need to retrieve the `SparkContext` from the `SparkSession`, stop it and recreate the `SparkSession` with the additional configuration. To do so, how can I **retrieve SparkContext from SparkSession**?

Comment: Isn't the SparkContext a child of SparkSession (`spark.sparkContext`)?

Comment: @ayplam do you mean the sparkContext() method in SparkSession? There is no clear document on its usage. When I try using it in my method, it throws reference error. I'm using spark 2.2.0.

Comment: What if you try accessing it without parenthesis? I'm on spark 2.2.0 as well and I can retrieve the sparkcontext fine that way via spark-shell

Comment: That works!! `var spCon = sparkSession.sparkContext`

The documentation kinda mislead me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just to post as an answer - the SparkContext can be accessed from SparkSession using `spark.sparkContext` (no parenthesis)

Comment: this is the correct syntax for the pyspark code

Answer (score 6):

The sparkContext field does not seem to be public anymore(I am using Spark 2.3.2), however, you can retreive it using a method of the same name:

```
spark.sparkContext()
```

This is applicable to Spark Java only.

Comment: correct but without parenthsis as spark context is not a callable function

Comment: @EssamEid  Added a note to the answer, the OP does not mention the language and going by the question heading being language neutral, hoping this will be helpful to people using Spark Java.