# Spark : Error Not found value SC in spark1.2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

getting the below error in spark shell 1.2.1

```
scala> sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/departments").collect().foreach(println)
<console>:11: error: not found: value sc
          sc.textFile("/user/clouderadepartments").collect().foreach(prenter code hereintln)
```

below is how i am starting spark-shell

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cd spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4
[cloudera@quickstart spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4]$ bin/spark-shell --master local
```

Comment: possible duplicate see [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625770/error-not-found-value-sc)

Comment: This issue is solved here :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/29224265/5724889 You can remove your duplicate question